# How to search an infinite list of words in sorted order for an index corresponding to a word as input

Tags: python, list, algorithm, stream

I am confounded by a hard problem I am having with a given stream I am dealing with to do better the linear time `O(n)`..

### Search an infinite list of words in sorted order for an index corresponding to a word as input

given an infinite list `["apple", "banana", "cat", "dog", ...]`
we have a class `A` where `A.get(2) # => "cat"`
write a function to return the index for the word given as input to the function like so:

```
A.get_index("cat") # => 2
```

*you can use A.get() but not python the .index() for sequences*

Comment: search an infinite list of words in sorted order.So while loop?

Comment: and you want none duplicates from A.get_index() I assume?

Comment: Using a `for` loop with `enumerate` should suffice here.

Comment: You can use a binary search

Comment: Can you show your try in O(N)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do it in `O(log n)` with a modification of binary search.

```
import bisect


def find(endless_haystack, needle):

    if endless_haystack[0] == needle:
        return 0

    i = 1
    hay = endless_haystack[i]
    while hay < needle:  # this is O(log n) where n is the index of the element
        i = 2 * i
        hay = endless_haystack[i]

    # from the loop before the element is between i and i // 2
    return bisect.bisect_left(endless_haystack, needle, i // 2, i)
```

Be aware that the above code is a sketch of an actual solution, you need to check for some edge cases.

Comment: If the infinite list it is not infinite then this is best +1

Comment: I think you meant `i = 0` and `i = 2 * i`?

Comment: @EricSteen Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use the built-in function `enumerate` who is giving you the index and the element:

```
def get_index(word, my_infinite_list):
    return next(i for i, e in enumerate(my_infinite_list) if e == word)
```

the built-in function `next` will make sure to iterate over your list until you find the wanted word

Comment: I am not sure you can use enumerate on an infinit list (or generator)

Comment: yes you can, here are the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: and the OP was showing a list in the question, maybe a big list, not an infinite list, there is no such thing :)

Comment: Also OP was saying an infinite loop, but if you look at the restriction to not use list.index make sense to show an example in o(n) this is the time complexity for list.index, OP may clarify if he will show his try

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate over the list by incrementing a counter until you hit a corresponding value

```
class A:
   [...]


   def get_index(self, item):
       i = 0
       while self.get(i) != item:
           i += 1
       return i
```

Note: That this is not very secure code. But because we assume the list is infinite, you don't risk to hit out of index. There is an overflow risk though...